# Groovy concurrency executor awaiting termination like join method in threads

Tags: groovy, concurrency, terminate, executorservice

i tried this with pool.shutdown() and pool.awaitTermination(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS) but it doesnt really want to wait for the tasks to be done before it prints me that it has finished. What am i doing wrong. BTW: The pool itself is the best thing i saw for multitasking till today. Glad i've found it here!!! The solution with signals like CountDownLatch doesnt seem to be the grooviest way... I am searching more for something like the join method as it is implemented for Threads.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import groovy.transform.Synchronized
import java.util.concurrent.*


class myThread extends Thread{
Integer timer=0
Integer count=0
String tn=''
String status=''

    def counter = new AtomicInteger()

    def void run() {
        println tn+' started ---- !!! ----'
        status='running'
        for( i in 1..count ) {
            sleep timer
            println tn+" Doing something loop $i"
            counter.incrementAndGet()
        }
        println tn+' finished - ### -'
        status='ok'
        this.join()
    }

}

def queue=[]

def mt1=new myThread(timer:550,count:10,tn:'t1',status:'')
def mt2=new myThread(timer:530,count:6,tn:'t2',status:'')
def mt3=new myThread(timer:550,count:10,tn:'t3',status:'')
def mt4=new myThread(timer:500,count:6,tn:'t4',status:'')

queue.push(mt1)
queue.push(mt2)
queue.push(mt3)
queue.push(mt4)


def maxConcurrent=2
def pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxConcurrent)
queue.each(){
    pool.submit(it)
}

pool.shutdown()
pool.awaitTermination(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// HOW DO I WAIT HERE???

println 'NOW its REALLY!!! finished!'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an ExecutorCompletionService

```
   def pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxConcurrent)

   def ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(pool);

   queue.each {
       ecs.submit(it, Void); // I think this is how to handle a void return
   }

   // take blocks until task finished so get probably not needed in this case
   queue.each {
       ecs.take().get();
   }

   pool.shutdown()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly the solution and works great with my extends Thread. Thank you!!!

Comment: Having your objects be Threads serves no useful purpose, I would have them just implement Runnable instead. It not that big a deal as you're not starting the thread but it does have an overhead.

Answer (score 4):

I believe to wait 'forever' you need to pass the magic parameters:

```
pool.awaitTermination( Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS )
```

Answer (score 1):

You are waiting for 0 seconds for the tasks to complete.  You should wait for a meaningful amount of time, maybe 10 seconds? or 1 minute?

```
pool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Just an FYI the awaitTerminiation will wait for the specified amount of time unless all currently queued items complete.  If they complete the method will exit and you will get to your `println` statement

Edit:

Just noticed you're submitting Threads to the executor service.  You should only be submitting Runnables. Granted it is compiling because Thread implements Runnable what is actually happening is the Thread of the executor service takes the Runnable (here your thread) off a work queue and executes its run() method.  Hence no need for a Thread being submitted.